# Jenkins Docker plugin volume mapping definition error

Tags: docker, jenkins, plugins, port

The Jenkins Docker plugin allows the user to specify port mappings that are normally specified as -p src:dest. However, the plugin documents fails miserably at explaining HOW to enter them into the field, since it doesn't show an example. How are they entered there and how are multiple mappings separated??

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70895210/jenkins-docker-plugin-volume-mount-what-syntax-to-use.

Comment: @MikiBelavista No, not even close.